# MySql - Como fazer uma Stored procedure ser ativado uma vez ao dia?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, eventos

Preciso de que uma Stored Procedure seja chamada todos os dias as 23:59:00 porém já tentei de algumas maneiras e quando chega nesse horário ele não executa!

```
    CREATE EVENT `ATUALIZARDADOS` ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-11-16 23:59:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO 
    begin
    CALL MULTAOFF();
    CALL RESERVAOFF();
    INSERT INTO configuracao (id,DiasMulta,DiasLivroMaior,DiasLivroMenor) 
    values ('8','2','3','4');
    end &&
    delimiter ;
```

detalhe, este trecho foi somente para que eu possa sabe se o evento está funcionando ou não)

```
    INSERT INTO configuracao (id,DiasMulta,DiasLivroMaior,DiasLivroMenor) 
    values ('8','2','3','4');
```

alguém pode me ajuda com este problema?

Comment: Verificou se tem [privilégios suficientes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-privileges.html) para agendar um evento? Se tem fez isso aqui `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` antes de usar o agendador de eventos?

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar criar um job que rodará este processo.

**Job**

O JOB é uma forma de auxiliar na manutenção com tarefas que devem ser executadas diversas vezes iguais ou em uma determinada data em especial sem precisar da intervenção do DBA, por exemplo, a desfragmentação de uma tabela no domingo. Como no domingo ninguém estará na empresa pode-se agendar o trabalho para ser executado nesse período.

Os JOBs podem ser criados de duas formas ou através do Enterprise manager ou por T-SQL, neste artigo vou mostrar duas formas que poderemos utilizar para criarmos um JOB.

**Exemplo**

A criação será algo nesta linha:

```
CREATE 
    EVENT `archive_blogs` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2011-07-24 03:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

        -- copy deleted posts
        INSERT INTO blog_archive (id, title, content) 
        SELECT id, title, content
        FROM blog
        WHERE deleted = 1;

        -- copy associated audit records
        INSERT INTO audit_archive (id, blog_id, changetype, changetime) 
        SELECT audit.id, audit.blog_id, audit.changetype, audit.changetime 
        FROM audit
        JOIN blog ON audit.blog_id = blog.id
        WHERE blog.deleted = 1;

        -- remove deleted blogs and audit entries
        DELETE FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

    END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Você pode colocar no corpo absolutamente qualquer execução válida de código.

[Leia mais](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)